# Crontab fails to run django manage commands

Tags: python, django, cron, psycopg2

I have written a script in django that send queued emails saved in the database to the users. There is a mangement command which should be called by crontab every hour to send the emails. However, whenever the crontab job get executed I receive the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My django app works fine without any error. But running crontab fails. The following is my crontab config:

```
0 * * * * source /opt/portal/virtEnv/bin/activate && python /opt/portal/websource/manage.py send_queued_messages --limit=1
```

Does anybody know how to solve the problem?

Comment: crontab has different environment variables. try `0 * * * * env > /tmp/env.txt` to see which variable is missing?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cant use the `activate` script in cronjob, just point it to the `python` interpreter which is in your virtualenv and it will work:

```
0 * * * * /opt/portal/virtEnv/bin/python /opt/portal/websource/manage.py send_queued_messages --limit=1
```

Comment: a silly question: do you have psycopg2 installed in your venv? .)

Answer (score 0):

try to point to python version inside virtualenv. Do not activate and use python.

Try this:

```
0 * * * * /opt/portal/virtEnv/bin/python /opt/portal/websource/manage.py send_queued_messages --limit=1
```

Edited: Removed 'source' at the beginning of the command.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the answer of @yedpodtrzitko

Comment: I just corrected my answer, since you're going to use the virtualenv's python, there's no need to use 'source'.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I had to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to the crontab configuration with the path pointing to the lib folder of postgres db.

Now it works smoothly.